# How to schedule a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to schedule a stored procedure once every night. I've followed steps online the outlines the this process:

```
SQL Sever Agent > Right click jobs & select New Job > Step > New > Select the stored procedure under type
```

But there is no option for stored procedure under the `Type` selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the `Type` drop down set to `Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)`, and set the Command to `EXEC [dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName]`, then click OK. Then go under `Shedules` and setup the time when you want it to run.

Answer (score 1):

You should type this query in your job

```
EXEC [schema].[StoredProcedureName]
```